# func(foo).push(bar) returns an integer

Tags: javascript

So I have a function "profile" that returns an array.
And I have a function "TMYW" whose results I want to add to the array that profile returns. So I tried something like this:

```
profile(m.hours).push(TMYW(m.hours));
```

Interestingly this whole statement returns the integer 3.

Just curious as to why this happens. Obviously it is easy to get the desired result by doing something like this:

```
var b = profile(m.hours);
b.push(TMYW(m.hours));
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push: _“Returns: The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.”_

Comment: Are you asking why `push` returns a number, or why the value of an expression is the result of the last operation performed in the evaluation of that expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the following regarding the use of [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

So in your case:

```
var b = profile(m.hours); // returns an array
b.push(TMYW(m.hours)); // returns the new length of b
```